# How to hide column based on condition in Jquery Datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

I'm stuck at hiding a column in JQuery DataTables based on condition, I've radio button list based on checked value I need to display particular column in datatables how I can achieve this? I'm hiding column like below but when I click on Excel button all hidden column are displaying in Excel without any data

```
if ($scope.searchAtDefaultVal == 'Voucher') {
   // hide column for voucher
   $scope.voucherSearchTable.column(8).visible(false);
   $scope.voucherSearchTable.column(9).visible(false);
   $scope.voucherSearchTable.column(10).visible(false);
   $scope.voucherSearchTable.column(11).visible(true);
}
else {
   $scope.voucherSearchTable.column(8).visible(true);
   $scope.voucherSearchTable.column(9).visible(true);
   $scope.voucherSearchTable.column(10).visible(true);
   $scope.voucherSearchTable.column(11).visible(false);
}
```

This code is working, but the problem is when I click on Excel button hidden column also display in Excel sheet without data.

Comment: I actually had done some DOM manipulation on a datatables table, and created my own excel exporting function to show it.

Answer (score 1):

When initializing the table, you can specify a selector of which data will be exported:

```
buttons: [
           {
             extend: 'excelHtml5',
             exportOptions: { 
                columns: ':visible' // <-- using datatables selector
            }
        }
    ]
```

That way only visible parts of the table will be exported, for more infomartion check https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/columns.html

Comment: I have added this but it will hide all hidden column from table in excel, how to show hidden columns in excel.